# Angular JS Long Press event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to increase value continuously on long press of "+" and decrease continuously on press on "-" please help.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.count = 0;
```

Please see http://plnkr.co/edit/3lpyqPPdAyXJOIMxM47V?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

To make continuously incrementation you can start an interval which will trigger incrementation  on `mouserdown` event, and clear it on `mouseup`.

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.count = 0;
  var interval;
  $scope.start = function(direction) {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      if(direction == 1) 
        $scope.count++;
      else
      $scope.count--;

      $scope.$apply();  
    }, 100);
  }

  $scope.clear = function() {
    clearInterval(interval); 
  }

});


<h1 ng-mouseup="clear()" ng-mousedown="start(1)">+</h1>
<h1 ng-mouseup="clear()" ng-mousedown="start(0)">-</h1>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/u7HA1XzbkdvGe3r2KEuH?p=preview